# How to present progress in my job

Tags: management

I'm learning new products in my company but don't have an idea of how should I present my progress to my boss or have evidence of it....any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest you give more information on your line of work. There are many ways to present this type of progress, and many approaches depend on the job/role/manager/company/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a status report, weekly.

Here's an example:

https://blog.weekdone.com/how-to-write-a-status-report-template-sample/

Answer (score 1):

Ask your boss, many workplaces have protocols in place for this already, ask the boss what is normal. One way is a tracking system where you log in your hours and what you were working on, but there's many different ways.

Don't go making up your own until you find out if there is already one, you'll just annoy the boss. In any case keep records of what you did. In some jobs at the end of each day I would add to a daily log text document, much like a diary, just the date and a summary of what was accomplished, and notes for anything I needed to remember to work on the next day. Only took a couple of minutes to type up each day. It was really for personal reference, but comes in handy for other things sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, assuming that a process doesn't already exist and you want to make one, try this:

You could provide an end of day email summary and email it off at the end of each day.

- Open the email without a recipient at the beginning of the day.
- Throughout the day simply add a bullet point for each thing that you have completed or done and add notes / talking points / ideas too.
- Ensure it's no longer than a couple of paragraphs.
- Once you're ready to send, enter the recipient's name. This ensures you don't accidentally email it midday.
- Obviously the recipient is your boss/manager.
- Keep the subject standard for these emails, something like `Joseph G - End of day summary, 2016-04-14`
- The talking points could even be things that might spur a meeting, to help you move in the right direction.
- Don't make it too long, make it so they can read the email in a couple minutes max.